# Python alternative to Java applet?

Tags: java, python, physics, simulation

Is there an alternative to making educational Java applets for physics simulations like projectile motion, gravity, etc?

Comment: Do you need them to run in a web browser like an applet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want it to run in a browser, you could use [PyJamas](http://pyjs.org/) - which is a Python-to-Javascript compiler and set of tools.

I'm not sure how well it is maintained these days, though.

Answer (score 7):

In this day and age, you might look to the HTML 5 canvas & JS.

Answer (score 5):

While I'm all for the "HTML5 & JS", you can consider [Jython](http://www.jython.org/) and simply write a Java Applet in Python (2.2.3, but...) Java is not only a language, so you're free to choose.

Answer (score 2):

You can run [IronPython](http://ironpython.net/) in [Silverlight](http://www.silverlight.net/) applications:

http://www.voidspace.org.uk/ironpython/silverlight/index.shtml

Comment: so from all the comments. Can I use pygame to create a physics simulation, then use PySide to add GUI elements and finally IronPython to put it on the web ???

Comment: yep, that in theory should be fine. One restriction I think you might bump into is that silver light won't allow you to run native CPython extensions.

Comment: hey, could you please expand on 'native Cpython' and also present a solution for this problem. This is my first encounter to a python project, thanks a ton.

Comment: I've just looked at the source for pygame and it contains an awful lot of C code. This isn't unusual in python extensions, but compiling it and convincing Silverlight to load the binary will present a serious issue and may not even be possible.

Answer (score 2):

[Brython](http://www.brython.info/) is your alternative. It allows you to define `"text/python"` scripts.

Answer (score 1):

You can run CPython in the browser using [empythoned](https://github.com/replit/empythoned). There is no proper interface from Python to the browser though, so it will be hard to do any GUI applications.